# CSS - Independent Translate and Scale functions?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning front-end and in the course that I am taking (?) , we use `transform: translate(-10px, 10px)`  but, I recently found an independent `translate` property that works and acts the exact same way. Does it mean that I should stop using `transform` and use individual properties instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to CSS documentation [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms):

> The translate, rotate, and scale properties allow authors to specify simple transforms independently, in a way that maps to typical user interface usage, rather than having to remember the order in transform that keeps the actions of translate(), rotate() and scale() independent and acting in screen coordinates.

So when you use `transform` and applies several transform functions (such as `translate`, `scale` or `rotate`), the functions order will effect the visual (which is hard to remember how each function effects the others).

When you use individual transforms you don't have to deal with it and the order doesn't matters.

Answer (score 1):

No You Should not stop using it! as Sometime you may find it Better than using Individual property, In Some Cases.

**Transform Property**
***The transform CSS property lets you rotate, scale, skew, or translate an element.***

`transform: translate(120px, 50%);`

`transform: scale(2, 0.5);`

**While Simply Translate**
***allows you to work with horizontal and vertical direction***

`transform: translate(100px, 200px);`

`transform: translate(100px, 50%);`

So, With transform you can do multiple things in one line of code like Scale, Translate ,Rotate etc.
and simply Translate allows you to work in horizontal and Vertical direction.

**Priority is given more to the individual Property *i.e translate* Here. Overriding of property can be Done**

Comment: There is a problem with this approach and that is when you assign  `transform` with multiple functions(  for example: `scale(1.5) rotate(45deg)` ) and later on you assign the property again with some other function ( for example: `translateY(-10px)` , it wouldn't add `translateY` to transform property, but instead it overwrites the whole property value! but apparently by using individual properties you wouldn't face that problem. So this is why I asked should we stop using transforms. Should we? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Yes! You are correct , I didn't knew that you wanted Information related to Priorities in CSS. By the way your concept is cleared now. Good Luck! also made little edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think transform:  translate(x,y); is the best way to move anything from its position. I did not hear about direct translate attribute which works.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the independed `translate` property is supported in all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate

The `transform: translate(x);` and `translate: x;` properties are basically the same. The difference is that the `transform` property is also used for scale, rotate, skew etc.

What does that matter?

Let's say we want to make an animation with keyframes. We want to change the position with translate but the object itself has a rotation. If we use `transform` we need to specify all values over and over again. If we use the single `translate` property, we have to edit only one value.

```css
.old-style,
.new-style {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.old-style {
  top: 30%;
  background: red;
  animation: old-style 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.new-style {
  top: 60%;
  background: blue;
  rotate: 45deg;
  animation: new-style 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes old-style {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
  100% {
     transform: translate(100vw, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes new-style {
  0% {
    translate: -100% -50%;
  }
  100% {
    translate: 100vw -50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="old-style"></div>
<div class="new-style"></div>
```